# MFC: Capturing Resizes

Tags: c++, mfc, controls, resize

Just wondering where is best to put functionality in an MFC application that is triggered when the whole window is resized. I was thinking mainfrm but I couldn't seem to capture any OnSize messages...

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

You didn't include any interesting details, so here are a few guesses (because *of course* the mainframe normally gets sent `WM_SIZE` messages...):

- You didn't set up your message handler properly. Perhaps you forgot the message map entry?
- You have an existing handler in place for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` that fails to call the default window procedure, thereby preventing `WM_SIZE` messages from being sent.

Comment: Yep, I was trying to catch ON_SIZE rather than WM_SIZE. Thanks for the tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are using the Multiple Document Interface ( MDI ) application type.  In this case, you should capture the WM_SIZE message in each of your views - the classes you have derived from CView.